# Recursive promise for failed requests

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a main function that makes a series of GET requests in parallel. Their status is evaluated using the `Promise.all` function.

```
var promises = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
{
   promises.push( REQ( list[ i ], 0 ) );
}

var responses = await Promise.all( promises );
```

The `REQ` function returns a promise.

```
async function REQ( url, attempts )
{
   await sleep( 5000 * attempts ); // Uses a promise with setTimeout

   return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      request( url, function ( error, response, body )
      {
         if ( error )
         {
            if ( attempts > ATTEMPT_THRESHOLD )
               reject( error );
            else
               return REQ( url, ++attempts );
         }
         else
         {
            if ( typeof body === 'undefined' || body.length === 0 )
            {
               if ( attempts > ATTEMPT_THRESHOLD )
                  reject( error );
               else
                  return REQ( url, ++attempts );
            }
            else
               resolve( { response, body } );
         }
      });
   });
};
```

The reason I've made the `REQ` function `async` is so that if a request fails, it gets re-attempted, but the re-attempt is delayed a little in case the server it's querying is congested.

The issue seems to be that in the Node console, the program hangs on a re-attempt, such that if a `REQ` fails, the re-attempt of it doesn't return to the original `REQ` and return the promise.

Comment: try to implement same logic with `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The re-attempt of it doesn't return to the original REQ and return the promise.

Of course not. In a `new Promise` constructor, you need to `resolve` the promise not `return` it.

It would be much better if you promisified on the lowest possible level, i.e. just wrap `request` and *only* `request`, not any of the retry business logic:

```
function requestAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve({response, body});
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can use `await` and `return` as usual.

```
async function REQ(url, attempts) {
  try {
    const res = await requestAsync(url);
    if (typeof res.body == "undefined" || res.body.length == 0)
      throw new Error("no response"); // or throw undefined to get the original behaviour
    return res;
  } catch(error) {
    if (attempts > ATTEMPT_THRESHOLD)
      throw error;
    ++attempts;
    await sleep(5000 * attempts);
    return REQ(url, attempts);
  }
}
```